# how to change bot background color

Tags: css, .net, azure, botframework

Curretly my Luis bot is embedded to a sharepoint website through the iframe html element and i want to add a custom styling, more specifically i want to change its backgrounf color.

According to this [tutorial](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/10/11/customize-web-chat-websites/) i'll have to clone the source code and edit the typescript and scss files. However my bot is hosted in azure so i don't know where to deploy the source code and how to reference it in my bot.

Is is through the iframe that i can define the background color ? if not can someone help me please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't apply styles using iframe. 
1. You need to create a direct line channel in your Bot Registration Portal and get your Direct Line secret.
2. Add these to your existing share point website instead of the iframe.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="bot"/>
    <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.js"></script>
    <script>
      BotChat.App({
        directLine: { secret: 'YOUR_DIRECT_LINE_SECRET' },
        user: { id: 'USER_ID' },
        bot: { id: 'YOUR_BOT_ID' },
        resize: 'detect'
      }, document.getElementById("bot"));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

For applying styles copy the [css file](https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.css) and customize it according to your need.

Comment: I recently began developping in bot framework so i don't really understand what you really mean.
What does it mean to create my own web chat instance ? where do i put the HTML code you've sent ? what do i need to change in my sharepoint website please ?

Comment: @SoufienHajji I would recommend you to first take a look into [Directline channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-concepts?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) In this link you will find some sample project as well. Please refer to sample project you will have better understanding of direct line support and how you will be able to build custom web chat window so that you could do the styling of our own choice. Bu default if you will use webchat given by microsoft you will not be able to do such styling.

Comment: @AnitaGeorge Thank you for the clarifications.

Just a quick question off the topic, is there a way to add the code above in the sharepoint web site ? because as far as i know sharepoint won't allow you to add scripts other than iframe

Comment: @HarshRaj Thanks